# Items collection must be empty before using ItemSource using custom list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my class `ResultEntity` if I do:

```
_resultMulti = new List<ResultTaskFund>();
```

I see the following error message:

```
"Exception: Items collection must be empty before using ItemSource."
```

I have seen lots of people also have had this error message and I've read the posts but I don't understand why I'm seeing this message. If I just declare `_resultMulti` without initialising a new list the application loads. I don't understand why though?

I have the following classes:

**ResultSummary**

```
 public class ResultEntity : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public List<ResultTaskFund> ResultsMulti
        {
            get { return _resultsMulti; }
            set { _resultsMulti = value; OnPropertyChanged("ResultsMulti"); }
        }

        List<ResultTaskFund> _resultMulti;


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

**ResultTaskFund**

```
 public class ResultTaskFund : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {            
        public string TaskName { get; set; }
        public ResultFund ABBC { get; set; }
        public ResultFund BBCA { get; set; }
        public ResultFund CCCA { get; set; }         
    }
```

**Result Fund**

```
    public class ResultFund
    {
        public string FundCode { get; set; }
        public ErrorAndWarningCodes  ErrCode { get; set; }
        public bool FundRequried { get; set; }
        public bool CheckRequired { get; set; }
        public string DisplayString { get; set; }
    }
```

**XAML**

```
 <DataGrid Grid.Row="0"
                      DataContext="{Binding ResultSummary}"
                      x:Name="dataGridResultMulti"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ResultsMulti, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      Style="{StaticResource DataGridTemplate}"
                      ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DG_ColumnHeader}"                                            
                      RowStyle="{StaticResource DG_Row}"
                      CellStyle="{StaticResource DG_Cell}"                                    
                      RowDetailsTemplate="{StaticResource DG_RowDetail}" 
                      RowHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DG_RowHeader}"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      Background="Silver"
                      RowHeaderWidth="30"                      
                      Margin="25,5,20,15">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Task" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding TaskName}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ABBC" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding ABBC.DisplayString}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="BBCA" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding BBCA.DisplayString}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="CCCA" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding CCCA.DisplayString}"/>
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Where did you declare ResultsFunds? Is it in another VM or class? Can you show us that class?

Comment: Apologies. I have more than one datagrid I'm working with and seem to have copied over the incorrect one. Updated my code, it should basically have been ResultsMulti and not ResultsFunds

Comment: I assume you have more typos since `ResultsMulti` and `_resultMulti` have different types; could you please check all the code (even the XAML)?

Comment: Sorry the code should now be correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding your `DataGridTextColumns` directly as items of the `DataGrid`, thus you are setting both the `Items` and `ItemsSource` property and you can only use one at the same time. Fix your columns configuration by using the `Columns` attached property:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Task" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding TaskName}"/>        
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ABBC" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding ABBC.DisplayString}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="BBCA" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding BBCA.DisplayString}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="CCCA" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding CCCA.DisplayString}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Ah yes! The headers on the datagrid now load up. However if I have _resultMulti = new List<blah>() then it still gives me the same error message?

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your column definitions with **DataGrid.Columns**. As you are binding it using ItemsSource you can't put any direct content in the definition. It is considering your columns as items of the grid which can't go with ItemsSource collection.